# I don't know how to restore a deleted document on Firestore using SnackBar Undo

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, android-snackbar

I'm creating a Task app using a FirestoreRecycler. I already created the method to delete an item from the RecyclerView but I don't know how to undo this action in Snackbar.

I have an Note class and a FirestoreRecycler both setting my Note and RecyclerView features.

It's my first time working with FirestoreUI.

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference notebookRef = db.collection("Notebook");

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private NoteAdapter adapter;
    CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView        = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        coordinatorLayout   = findViewById(R.id.coordinator);
        setUpRecyclerView();
        enableSwipeToDeleteAndUndo();

        FloatingActionButton buttonAddNote = findViewById(R.id.button_add_note);
        buttonAddNote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewNoteActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }

    public void setUpRecyclerView(){
        Query query = notebookRef.orderBy("priority", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Note>().setQuery(query, Note.class).build();
        adapter = new NoteAdapter(options);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public void enableSwipeToDeleteAndUndo(){
        SwipeToDeleteCallback swipeToDeleteCallback = new SwipeToDeleteCallback(this) {
            @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

                final int position  = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                final String item   = adapter.getItem(position).toString();
                boolean clicked = false;

                adapter.deleteItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());

                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Nota foi removida da lista " , Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                snackbar.setAction("DESFAZER", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        adapter.restoreItem(item, position);
                        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
                    }
                });
                snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                snackbar.show();
            }
        };

        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(swipeToDeleteCallback);
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you delete a document in Firestore, it's gone for good.  There is no undelete feature.

What you're trying to do is likely not very easy with the adapter provided by FirebaseUI.  The only way you can reasonably implement an undo feature is to have the delete function not actually delete the document, and instead just update the UI to remove the view.  You would have to scheduling the deletion to happen some time later.  The undo option would then just restore the visibility of the deleted document and cancel the delayed deletion.

Also consider just adding a new boolean field to the document to mark that it's deleted or not, and use that in a filter for the query you pass to FirebaseUI.  The field would have to be present on every document in order for it to filter correctly.  After the UI is done, you would then have to figure out how to actually delete all the documents you marked for deletion in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

when you delete a document in firestore it's impossible to recover it ,
but you can maybe create 2 collections and when deleting something delete it only from the first collection so you can get it back from the 2nd